# .Clearcontents shiftxlUp

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I am trying to clear contents of an active row and shifting the bottom rows up. I want to clear instead of delete because I have data validation and formulas in my cells. I keep getting an error when using the following VBA, i understand that shift:=xlUp will only work with a .delete command. Is there any way to have this work with .clearcontents?

```
Sub shiftmeup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Contacts") '/// The underhood of my contacts
    With ws.Range("D11:BL392")
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).ClearContents shift:=xlUp
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Clearing contents and shifting cells up is the same thing as deleting a row.  Any references to cells should automatically update as long as they were set up properly in the first place.

Comment: ClearContents does not take any parameters and does not move rows.  See the documentation for more info.  [Here is a link](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/39731-data-validation-for-a-column-when-row-deleted?p=411976#post411976) with an example of deleting rows with Data Validation in place.  Also the [`Worksheet.Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-rows-property-excel) property (parent of the [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-delete-method-excel) method.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "shift the bottom rows up" without deleting. `ClearContents` literally just does that, clears the cell's `.value` and then doesn't modify the `xlsx` beyond that.